# How do I create sub-headers within a View Section?

Tags: listview, swiftui

**Goal:** To have **sub-headers** with associated rows beneath main headers of a View.
Details:

```
Array {
   <Header>
      <SubHeader>
         <Item 1>
         <Item 2>
      <SubHeader>
         <Item 3>
         <Item 4>
   ...
}
```

Here's the code for the standard set of headers with their repective members:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Important tasks")) {
            Text("Item 1")
            Text("Item 2")
            Text("Item 3")
            }
            Section(header: Text("Regular tasks")) {
            Text("Item 4")
            Text("Item 5")
            Text("Item 6")
            }
        }
        .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
    }
}
```

Here's the result:

[image]

I'm trying to add sub-headers with their elements per header.
Here's my initial attempt:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Important tasks")) {
                Text("Item 1")
                Text("Item 2")
                Text("Item 3")

                Section(header: Text("Regular tasks")) {
                    Text("Item 4")
                    Text("Item 5")
                    Text("Item 6")
                }
            }
        }
        .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
    }
}
```

Here's the output (not quite what I had in mind):

[image]

The quickest/simplest workaround is to change the font/padding of the selected sub-header element to give it a 'header' look.

What's the recommended SwiftUI way?

Answer (score 0):

The only apparent *canned solution* is to use the **SidebarListStyle()**:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Important tasks")) {
                Text("Item 1")
                Text("Item 2")
                Text("Item 3")

                Section(header: Text("Regular subtasks #1")) {
                    Text("Item 4")
                    Text("Item 5")
                    Text("Item 6")
                }
                Section(header: Text("Different subtasks #2")) {
                    Text("Item 7")
                    Text("Item 8")
                    Text("Item 9")
                }
            }
        }
        .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
    }
}
```

The Output:

[image]

I would like to see other designs/ideas as well.